# JBOSS 7 - Spring ContextLoaderListener ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, jboss, classnotfoundexception, jboss7.x

im trying to migrate my JBOSS 5.1 application to JBOSS 7.0.2. In admin console i select deployments -> add content and my .war and try to enable it.
I already resolved some problems, but cant figure out this one: (in short, in long at the end)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener from [Module "deployment.ZaprogsProject.war:main" from Servic
e Module Loader]
```

I copied to `JBOSS7\standalone\lib\` the following files:

```
spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

I have read this: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7 *(Debug and resolve ClassNotFoundExceptions and NoClassDefFoundErrors)* but cant find a solution for me and still getting the same error. Can anyone help?

```
22:19:12,091 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ZaprogsProject.war".INSTALL: o
rg.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ZaprogsProject.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "ZaprogsProject
.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [:1.7.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [:1.7.0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEClassConfigurationProcessor$1.compute(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:141)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEClassConfigurationProcessor$1.compute(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:122)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:40)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEApplicationDescription.getClassConfiguration(EEApplicationDescription.java:183)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription.createConfiguration(ComponentDescription.java:153)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:70)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener from [Module "deployment.ZaprogsProject.war:main" from Servic
e Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.7.0]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) [:1.7.0]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEClassConfigurationProcessor$1.compute(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:139)
        ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not put those JARs in that directory.  Try them in your WAR file's WEB-INF/lib.  The class loader will find them there.

You need to understand that all Java EE app servers use a hierarchy of class loaders: bootstrap, server, application.  JBoss wasn't finding that class when it needed to.

Comment: Thanks worked. Why does it not work in the lib folder and what are the advantages and disadvantages of keeping the JARs inside the WAR?

Comment: That bloats my war from 11MB to nearly 70MB. Is there a way to keep these JARs outside? 70MB WAR building would took forever....

Comment: Disk space is cheap.  You're fretting about something that doesn't matter in the larger scheme of things.

Answer (score 5):

JBoss AS 7 does class-loading in a diff way.

All classes in the WAR are loaded with the same class loader. This means classes packaged in the WEB-INF/lib are treated the same as classes in WEB-INF/classes.
Hence it works for you.

But as you have said correctly your WEB-INF/lib is bloated.This would not be the correct way.

You would need to make a module :
Goto modules folder, make folder structure with main folder and put your jar and modules.xml with entries in it.
Something like :

```
<main-class name="org.jboss.msc.Version"/>

<resources>
    <resource-root path="jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.modules"/>

    <!-- Optional deps -->
    <module name="javax.inject.api" optional="true"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.threads" optional="true"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.vfs" optional="true"/>
</dependencies>
```

You would also need to update MANIFEST as well.
Details are here :
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Module+descriptors

Answer (score 1):

There is a major change Jboss 7 when compared to previous versions.If you want to access any libraries outside your war file, it should be installed as module.
Check https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Introduction 
In this case you should install Spring as module and specify the name of the module as dependency in your application's manifest file(check [Manifest module information](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Manifest+module+information))

Comment: Looks like i need this: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Filesystem+module+loader ?

Comment: As far as I know, you need just define module and install it in Jboss. Then add it as dependency in your manifest. This what I have done when  application(quartz) needed access to classes in ojdbc. You probably don't need to deal with module loader's directly. Let me know if this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

In case the issue started occurring all of a sudden(just like in my case), deleting the application (**MyApp**) physically from #JBOSS_HOME#\standalone\deployments\ **MyApp.war** worked for me.