# Auto deploy app with jar library

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, jboss

I try deploy web application using eclipse and maven as a dependency resolver. But I see exeptions:

```
    00:05:31,883 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener from [Module "deployment.SpringMVCreName.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]

00:05:31,892 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module "deployment.SpringMVCreName.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]

00:05:32,007 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SpringMVCreName]] (MSC service thread 1-5) Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener from [Module "deployment.SpringMVCreName.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3342) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]

00:05:32,024 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SpringMVCreName]] (MSC service thread 1-5) Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
00:05:32,029 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Error listenerStart
00:05:32,029 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Context [/SpringMVCreName] startup failed due to previous errors
00:05:32,041 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./SpringMVCreName: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./SpringMVCreName: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]

00:05:32,047 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
00:05:32,048 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 3974ms - Started 170 of 249 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
00:05:32,252 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "SpringMVCreName.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./SpringMVCreName" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./SpringMVCreName: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
00:05:32,278 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SpringMVCreName.war in 26ms
00:05:32,280 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./SpringMVCreName: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./SpringMVCreName: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

00:05:32,282 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./SpringMVCreName" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./SpringMVCreName: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
```

I found solutions this problem: [JBOSS 7 - Spring ContextLoaderListener ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560990/jboss-7-spring-contextloaderlistener-classnotfoundexception)

**It is very strange because..**

Theroetical this problem is overcome but, yesterday I develop this same application on this same server with this same settings and with this same jar fetched using maven without any exeptions.

I would like ask how solve problem without copy-pase `.jar` files. And how do this automatical without manual (explicity) user intervention.

I would like only do:

- create project
- resolve dependency using m2e
- and deploy on `jboss` using `run`

Comment: Can you clean up your question slightly, as there seems to be two different topics here. 1.) build automation, 2.) class not found issue

Comment: I think that this topic have two branch, but main question is why deploy on boss does't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate the java classpath. The classes must be available for the classloader to load when your application asks  for them.

Typically for a web application, this means the jar's containing the classes need to be packaged into the /WEB-INF/lib directory of the WAR.

With Maven, you should be using packaging type **war**, not **jar**. Then the maven's war plugin (i.e. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) will automatically package any dependencies into the war's lib folder.

To have the dependencies resolved using m2e, you should

- ensure that the project compiles and packages from the command line using maven
- delete the project from eclipse (don't delete the files)
- delete the eclipse meta data files (i.e. .project, .classpath, .settings)
- open eclipse
- import --> import existing maven projects --> select your project

At this point m2e will create all the eclipse settings for you, including a dynamic classpath library.

Comment: At the first i building `.war` file without use maven. I use maven only for dependency resolve purpose. Next, yesterday I have this same `.jar` in project path. All working correct. How it is possible ?

Comment: Why not use maven the way it was intended for the full compilation and packaging of your war?

Comment: Ok I have `*.war` file bulding via maven using war plugin. In war archive exist `/WEB-INF/lib/` directory with `.jar` dependent. But I still see exeptions, even after manual deploy into jboss directory..

Comment: In tomcat 7 is possible start application.

Comment: so your issue is that you can start the application in tomcat 7 but not in jboss? because you get a class not found exception for org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Comment: I try start on jboss. But if app don't starting on jboss I try also deploy on tomcat. Question is- why app doesn't runing correct on `Jboss`?
Edit:
After `commenting` line:

`<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>`

Apps started on Jboss. Why It does't runing with uncomment line?

Comment: A *single* version of this class needs to be in the class loader. My guess is that jboss and tomcat behave differently because they have different classes loaded by the class loader. JBoss comes with additional libraries, which are added to the class loader. My Guess is you may be getting a conflict.